# Regex for AND operator

Tags: regex

I need a regex that needs to match

`start from origin to id=` and `;to cases.`

I applied "OR" condition but it satifies only one condition. Any suggestions?

```
origin=eBook;id=**N27F-00000-00**;type=cases
```

Regex:

`(^(.*id=)|(;type=cases.*))`

Comment: As per the regex tag, please specify the language or tool that you are using.

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: regex need to match "origin=eBook;id=" and ";type=cases". only the id value(N27F-00000-00) needs to be unmatched.

Comment: basically you want the id part with everything else removed ?

Comment: in that case Sam's answer should work for you it will give you the result in \1 or $1

Comment: and yes one more thing why do you think your regex is wrong ?. see here its working as you want : http://regex101.com/r/zS2yI1 see the substitution result. are you using the `g` modifier ?

Comment: @aelor: Its matching first part alone. "origin=eBook;id=" not ther second one. I am using a tool that will work same as regexpal.com. first i will match then wil replace the matching regex value to get the ID alone.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaking some fundamentals of regular expressions, which I'll explain in a minute.  But for now, try this:

```
id=(.*?);type=cases
```

1. Regular expressions try to match *as much as* a string as possible.  This means it can match part of a string, and you don't need to use `.*` on either side of the string (unless you want to capture that information).
2. Since we aren't matching the `.*` in the beginning, you won't need to start from the beginning of the string (`^`).
3. There is no such thing as an `AND` operator, since an entire regular expression must match by default.

[Link](http://regex101.com/r/sR5yO3)

---

**Update**

This will still *match* the whole chunk of regex.  Since I used parenthesis around the important part (`N27F-00000-00`), it will be placed in a ["match group"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).  If you don't want to deal with match groups, you can use ["lookarounds"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=id=).*?(?=;type=cases)
```

[Link](http://regex101.com/r/vY1cI5)

Comment: its matching "id=N27F-00000-00;type=cases" all the values.

Comment: Look in my Regex101 links, I've never had good luck with lookbehind syntax in RegexPal. Also, try it in your actual code. If it doesn't work then, I need to know which language you are using (can't really help if you don't help me). Also, you can always use my first solution and look in the match group `$1`.